# how can i set grid element rotation

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Please tell me how to set the order of grid elements from bottom to top, i.e., now there are two columns from 1 to 10, and the default order is left to right. I need to do this: 1st column from 1..5 (from top to bottom); 2nd column 6..10 (from top to bottom).

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%; 
}

.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 50px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="grid_element">
    1
    </div>
    <div class="grid_element">
    2
    </div>
    <div class="grid_element">
    3
    </div>
    <div class="grid_element">
    4
    </div>
    <div class="grid_element">
    5
    </div>
    <div class="grid_element">
    6
    </div>
    <div class="grid_element">
    7
    </div>
    <div class="grid_element">
    8
    </div>
    <div class="grid_element">
    9
    </div>
    <div class="grid_element">
    10
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set an **explicit** number of rows and then tell the grid to flow in columns.

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, auto);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="grid_element">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="grid_element">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="grid_element">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="grid_element">
      4
    </div>
    <div class="grid_element">
      5
    </div>
    <div class="grid_element">
      6
    </div>
    <div class="grid_element">
      7
    </div>
    <div class="grid_element">
      8
    </div>
    <div class="grid_element">
      9
    </div>
    <div class="grid_element">
      10
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another idea without setting the number of rows:

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow:dense;
  grid-gap: 50px;
}

.content > * {
  grid-column:1;
}
.content > *:nth-child(n + 6) {
  grid-column:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="grid_element">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="grid_element">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="grid_element">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="grid_element">
      4
    </div>
    <div class="grid_element">
      5
    </div>
    <div class="grid_element">
      6
    </div>
    <div class="grid_element">
      7
    </div>
    <div class="grid_element">
      8
    </div>
    <div class="grid_element">
      9
    </div>
    <div class="grid_element">
      10
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is nice :-)